can we call child component inside parent component using Slot
I have 2 Astro Components
Parent.astro and Child.Astro
where I want to pass props to Child Astro file within a loop
tried this way
Parent.astro
---
import Letter from "./Child.astro";


type Props =  {
  title: string;
  list: string[];
}

const { title, list} = Astro.props;

---

  <div class="container">
    <h1>{title}</h1>
    <div >
      <!--theis doesn't works-->
      {list.map((item) =>  <Child entity={item}></Child> )}
      <!--below works-->
      {list.map((item) =>  <p>{item}</p> )}
    </div>
</div>


Child.Astro
---
type Props = {
  letter: string;
  code: string | number;
}

const {letter, code} = Astro.props

---
<div class="letterClass" >
  <p>{letter}</p>
  <p id="tgt">{code}</p>
</div>

but it is not working when passing <Child> inside map. what am I missing here?
while calling <Alphabet list={['a','b']}> from other component
or can we use <Slot/> inside .map
{list.map((item) =>  <Slot> )} ?

what do you mean with "it is not working"?

Your child component expect letter and code as props while you are using an entity prop in its Parent. Also there is a mismatch between your import name and the component name. So I don't see how this could work. You should use <Letter code={item} letter={item} /> instead.
It's not possible to use  with map because Astro does not support dynamic slot names (see: https://github.com/withastro/astro/issues/5066 ).

Thanks. I thought it will throw error when somethintg is missing while it is required props by ts server but it does not throw/complain any error
